# Highcharts based Graph export as image file

Tags: javascript, gwt, highcharts, html5-canvas

I have been developing (more like modifying the project from the last developers) this website that displays charts and graphs which uses Highcharts and GWT. The problem I face now is that the image and CSV Export functions do not work properly and it is difficult to track down the cause of problem because:

1.) The former developers did the spaghetti coding - no comments or proper variable naming.

2.) The export system use Batik software which is based on windows server which I concern that this will not work when the website is moved to Linux server in the future.

My solution to the mentioned problems is to create new function that export the canvas based graph as image by limiting the area of export in the specific Div.

The example of graph on the actual website is in the following link

http://mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my/?page_id=232#!from=2014&to=2015

I am not sure if my solution is practical so I would like to ask if it is possible to do what I thought and is there any tutorial or some resource I should look up to.

If it is not possible is there any other solution you guys can suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: just want to know, is there a reason to not use highcharts export functionality?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a right place to ask that kind of questions, but reading [Highcharts docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export) is a good idea, I think ;)